# onclick event not working after ie7 reload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, onclick, onload, dynamic

I am using Javascript to dynamically create part of my page content.  A routine that generates a set of img tags is called from the window.onload event.  Those img tags are assigned attributes, including an onclick event.  The img tags host thumbnail images that, when clicked, change the src property of the image in the main view div.

Everything works properly in FF 3.5.  I can reload the page and the dynamically generated onclick events continue to fire as expected.  In IE7 everything works normally until I reload the page.  At that point events that were hard coded into the xhtml section continue to work as expected, and the dynamically generated img tags are shown on the page, but their onclick events fail to work.

How can I get IE7 to implement the dynamically generated click events on reload?

Answer (score 0):

If you have write any JavaScript to reload page then give return true at the end of JavaScript function. Hope it will work.

Comment: I gave that a try and it did not work.  

The code in question is for an ebay template I am developing.  The page currently exists in the "test auctions" category on the ebay site.  If anyone wants to see the problem in action, use the link below.  To reiterate, the problem is that the click event for the thumbnails does not fire in IE7 after a page reload (have not yet tested other versions of IE).  It does work in FF3.5.

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=120543529870